# How to call a function with params in Iframe after loading the iframe in the pop-up dynamically created?

Tags: javascript, json, printing, underscore.js, popupwindow

In my app, I am loading search result. while the user click on the `print` button I would like to create a `pop-up`. ( this is ok ) But when I create a `pop-up`, I would like to load my `Iframe` in the `pop-up`. Again I need to call a `Iframe function` with the parameter which i receiving from parent page, Because I am using `underscore` template. I would like to call couple of `ajax` request with api url - (which i getting from parent page as parameter ) and need to create and append the html in to the `Iframe` - to `print` (once the template generated `html` )

I am sorry for big summary, Even if any one gives good approach even apart from this as well appreciated or could any one show me the correct approach.

**simply : html page to popup + load iframe + call iframe function with html page params + create html and append in Iframe + print... - please help me in this..**

Thanks In advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly, when the customer requests "print all", you want to show them the paginated data on separate pages?

Comment: some what you are correct. please see the question updated with summary

Comment: you basically wrote down how you should do it. What have you tried and what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the css rules depending on the media used with [CSS media types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).

For example:

```
@media print {
  body { font-size: 10pt }
}
@media screen {
  body { font-size: 13px }
}
@media screen, print {
  body { line-height: 1.2 }
}
```

Comment: Please understand my question, I don't want to create a popup. without a popup how can i update the printable data one by one and print all..

Comment: I do not have spoken of any popup! I Understand that you have a paginated list of elements and you want print all the pages in one step and with perhaps a different presentation.