# 'td' - element not appending to 'tr' element using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically creating a table with 3 col based. I am using this code, But the `td` is not appending to `tr`.

Here is my code :

```
var l = 10;

for(i=0; i<l; i++){
    if(i%3==0){
       var tr = $('tbody').append('<tr/>')
    }
    $(tr).append('<td>'+i+'</td>'); //not appending to tr element!
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ep1uabu/)

Comment: `$('tbody').append('<tr/>')` gives you back the `tbody`.

Comment: I recommend to make use of jQuery's [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/append/): *"The `.append()` and `.appendTo()` methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target. With `.append()`, the selector expression preceding the method is the container into which the content is inserted. With `.appendTo()`, on the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted into the target container."*

Comment: @FelixKling That doesn't explain the problem in OP's code. And the documentation surprisingly does not explain what the `append()` method returns, which _is_ the root of the problem here.

Comment: Because all jQuery methods return the first object so chaining works.

Comment: @JLRishe: True... I thought it was clearer in the docs... that's what I get from blindly copying it (I still recommend it to read it though ;) ).

Comment: @thebjorn: Nope, `$(this).children()` does certainly not return `$(this)`.

Comment: @FelixKling there are always exceptions ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
   var tr = $('<tr />').appendTo('tbody'); // this returns the tr element.
```

**[THE WORKING DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/4ep1uabu/1/)**

Comment: Accepted. do you have any idea about this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479871/how-to-call-a-function-with-params-in-iframe-after-loading-the-iframe-in-the-pop

Answer (score 1):

`$('tbody').append('<tr/>')` returns the `<tbody>`'s `jQuery`.

You should do this:

```
var body = $('tbody'),
    l = 10,
    tr,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
       tr = $('<tr />').appendTo(body); 
    }

    tr.append('<td>' + i + '</td>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var i, il, tr, td;
var tbody = $('tbody');

for (i = 0, il = 10; i < il; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
       tr = $('<tr />').appendTo(tbody);
    }

    $('<td />').text(i).appendTo(tr);
}
```

Comment: I'll give you a point if you use something besides a lower cased `L` as a variable name (and change the `++i` to `i++`..)

Comment: @thebjorn Why do you take issue with `++i`?

Comment: @JLRishe because it's off-by-one.  Idiomatic for is `for (i=0; i<length; i++)` if you want to be obtuse you can start at `i=1` or compare with `i<=length` -- and then use `++i`, but that's just confusing.

Comment: @thebjorn It's not off-by-one. Using `++i` or `i++` there will have exactly the same result aside from perhaps a negligible speed difference (`++i` tends to be faster because it requires fewer operations).

Comment: Yep. @thebjorn, The last time I had perf tested these, `++i` had (probably negligible) better perf performance. According to [this](http://jsperf.com/plusplusi-vs-iplusplus), that is not the case.